# Replace and Append is not working in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to append value with replace value in column no2, and i tried like appending my existing value with replace value, but not working.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df=pd.DataFrame({'no1':[20,20,40,10,50],
                 'no2':[123,20,123,40,50],
                 'no3':[30,10,50,40,50]})
lookup=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                     'id':[123,20,30,40,50]})
df['no2']+str(df['no2'].replace(dict(zip(lookup.id, lookup.Name)), inplace =True))
df
```

the output i am getting-

```
no1 no2 no3
0   20  A   30
1   20  B   10
2   40  A   50
3   10  D   40
4   50  E   50
```

but i need output like this- -**(appending my existing value of no2 with lookup value)**

```
    no1 no2    no3
0   20  123-A   30
1   20  20-B    10
2   40  123-A   50
3   10  40-D    40
4   50  50-E    50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `replace()`:

```
df['no2']=df['no2'].astype(str)+'-'+df['no2'].replace(dict(lookup[['id','Name']].values))
```

**OR**

try via `map()`:

```
df['no2']=df['no2'].astype(str)+'-'+df['no2'].map(dict(lookup[['id','Name']].values))
```

**Note:**

```
#you can also replace this code:
dict(lookup[['id','Name']].values)
#to:
lookup.set_index('id')['Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['no2'] = df['no2'] + '-' + lookup['id']
```